# Change timeout duration

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am building Angular 6 app where I have multiple items and each item have some configuration. On each item I defined duration how long this item must be visible.

I created this, but I am interested if this can be written in rxjs or maybe if there is simpler solution.

```
const timer = () => {
    this.counter++;
    this.currentItem = this.items[this.counter % this.items.length];
    setTimeout(timer, this.currentItem.duration);
};
setTimeout(timer, this.currentItem.duration);
```

Answer (score 1):

With RxJS 6 you could do something like this

```
from(items)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(item => of(null) // Wait until the previous inner observable completes
     .pipe(
       delay(item.duration), // Delay emission after this value
       ignoreElements(),
       startWith(item),
     )
    ),
    repeat(),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

See live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo?file=index.ts

Comment: Great. How can I do this in loop? When last item is completed, go to first element again.

Comment: So current item won't be long for example 1000ms, but it will be long how next item have duration set up.

Comment: No the delay is set for the current item.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-sl347u?file=index.ts When I logged to the console, second item have delay of third element and it is shown only 1 second.

Comment: So what do you want to do? First log the item and then make a delay or you want to first make delay and then log the item?

Comment: I want to take the item and its duration and show it. For example if first item have duration 1000, then it must be visible for 1s. Then go to the second item which have duration 5000, show it for 5s.

Comment: Ok so you want it exactly the other way around. See my update. I'm using `startWith` to emit the item immediately and then `delay(item.duration)` and `ignoreElements()` to make the delay.